# MS Access SQL subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access

I need to be able to return a treeview like structure using SQL via MS Access. I am however unsure how i can perform an inner join subquery. My code thus far is

```
 SELECT o.name,o.pdata1,o.pack_ID,p.name,p.pack_ID,p.parent_ID
    FROM   t_obj AS o
    INNER JOIN  t_pack AS p on o.Pack_ID = p.Pack_ID
    WHERE o.pdata1 IN (
        SELECT o2.pdata1
        FROM t_obj AS o2
        )
    ORDER BY p.parent_ID ASC
```

As there is a relationship between o.pack_ID and o.pdata1, i also need to perform a join on itself.

**Sample data**

```
o.Name          o.Pack_ID    p.Pack_ID   p.Name      p.Parent_ID   o.PDATA1 
Artifacts       1            1            AC         0             297
Template        1            1            AC         0             281
WA              1            1            AC         0             361
Alisha          361          361          WA         1             611 
Damian          361          361          WA         1             480
ABC             297          297          Artifacts  1             
DEF             297          297          Artifacts  1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of "WHERE o.pdata1 IN (SELECT o2.pdata1 FROM t_obj AS o2)"? That sub is referencing the same table (t_obj) as the parent query, meaning it is not doing anything, because obviously all values of pdata1 in table t_obj are in that table.

Comment: Can you provide a small amount of sample data and expected output?

Comment: @Brian DeMilia - I updated the post with some sample data. The expected output is to display a treelike view or at least a parent-child like relationship even if it is tabular.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey . . . Please edit your question to show desired results.  Remember a SQL query returns a result set as a table and MS Access doesn't support recursion.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - The reason i didn't include desired results as i am unsure of what MS Access is capable of. Would i be able to show the relationships in tabular format or can i have Excel run the query and return the appropriate view?

Comment: @peanutsmonkey Although it depends on what you mean with respect to 'tree-like' you're probably going to have to create a 'report' in access that uses the sql result as its data source to achieve what you want. I'm just speculating though as I'm not sure what you want.

Comment: @Brian DeMilia - I mean some sort of hierarchical structure. What would be the best way to represent this in tabular format as i am unsure of the capabilities of Access.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey if you add the desired output -- just based on the output you provided above -- we can probably better help. Is the output you're getting above what you want just not formatted in the fashion that you want or is the resulting data itself also not what you want?

Comment: @Brian DeMilia - The resulting data to begin with is not what i expect it to be. I'm quite certain the SQL query isn't correct.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey it would help significantly to know what output you are expecting. And also the rows from each of these two tables that lead to that result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57627/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-brian-demilia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further discussion -

```
select o.name as parent_name, p.name, p.package_id, p.parent_id
  from t_pack p
 inner join t_obj o
    on CStr(p.parent_id) = o.pdata1
union all
select o2.name as parent_name, o.name, o.package_id, o.package_id
  from t_obj o
 inner join t_obj o2
    on CStr(o.package_id) = o2.pdata1
 order by parent_id
```

Make a pivot table if you want to show each parent_name only once going down.

CStr is being used because pdata1 is not a numeric data type but needs to be joined with a field that is a numeric data type. (just restating so that others are aware)